# Python CSV writer, how to handle quotes in order to avoid triple quotes in output

Tags: python, csv

I am working with Python's CSV module, specifically the writer.  My question is how can I add double quotes to a single item in a list and have the writer write the string the same way as a print statement would?

for example:

```
import csv
#test "data"
test = ['item1','01','001',1]

csvOut = csv.writer(open('file.txt','a')) #'a' used for keeping past results
test[1] = '"'+test[1]+'"'
print test
#prints: ['item1', '"01"', '001', 1]
csvOut.writerow(test)
#written in the output file: item1,"""01""",001,1
#I was expecting: item1,"01",001,1
del csvOut
```

I tired adding a quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE option, but that raised an error.  I am guessing this is related to the many csv dialects, I was hoping to avoid digging too far into that.

In retrospect I could probably have built my initial data set smarter and perhaps avoided the need for this situation but at this point curiosity is really getting the better of me (this is a simplified example): how do you keep the written output from adding those extra quotes?

Comment: Writing output this way is part of generating a valid CSV that represents your data the way you've specified. Generating an invalid CSV file (or one that writes quotes-as-syntax when you've passed in quotes-as-data) would be a bug, not a feature.

Comment: What do you _want_ it to look like? And what other CSV-handling code do you want to interoperate with? (If you're creating files to be fed into Excel, or `np.loadtxt`, or whatever, your output had better be readable by that other program.)

Comment: The existing answers cover it, but to be perfectly clear it's worth noting that if you read the output back in with `csv.reader` you will get your original string with the quotes back. Try it.

Comment: @JasonS: Good point; I probably didn't need to bring up Excel or `np.loadtxt`; the most common thing you want to interoperate with is your own code. :)

Comment: I was trying to make this interoperable with other software down the line but didn't want to muddy the waters. I was also trying to understand what was going on (but wanted to ask a specific answerable question).  In case others stumble on this, if you're interested in better interoperability with other programs google for things like "schema.ini" and "csvt file extension" (solved my ultimate problem, but answer below still helped)

Comment: @RichardW: It was a good question (that's why I upvoted it), but adding more information after the core question can sometimes make it even better—e.g., even if it isn't an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if it might _look_ like one, explaining why it isn't can help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not actually triple-quoting, although it looks that way. Try it with another example to see:

```
test = ['item1', 'abc"def']
```

Now you'll see that it writes this:

```
"abc""def"
```

In other words, it's just wrapping quotes around your string, and escaping the literal quote characters by doubling them, because that's how default Excel-style CSV handles quote characters.

The question is, what format *do* you want here? Almost anything you want (within reason) is doable, but you have to pick something. Backslash-escaping quotes? Backslash-escaping everything instead of using quotes in the first place? Single quotes instead of double quotes?

For example, this looks like an answer:

```
csvOut = csv.writer(open('file.txt','a'), quotechar="'")
```

… until you have an item like `Filet O'Fish` and the whole thing gets single-quoted and the `'` gets doubled and you have the exact same problem you were trying to avoid. If you're aiming for human readability, and `'` is a lot less common in your data than `"`, that may actually be the right answer, but it's not a perfect answer.

And really, no answer can be perfect: you need some way to either quote or escape commas—and other things, like newlines—and the way you do that is going to add at least one more character that needs to be quote-doubled or escaped. If you know there are never any commas, newlines, etc. in your data, and there's at least one other character you know will never show up, you can get away with setting either `quotechar` to that other character, or `escapechar` to that other character and `quoting=QUOTE_NONE`. But the first time someone unexpectedly uses the character you were sure would never appear, your code will break, so you'd better actually be sure.

Comment: Just to add on, in case anyone else finds this useful in the future:  I tried setting quotechar=" " based on this answer (yes, perhaps silly in practice but trying to understand the behavior here) and got output the I was after: 'item1,"01",001,1' (I didn't realize the default behavior was to use  double-quotes as escape characters, i thought it was translating to the python triple-quote method of designating a string)

Comment: @RichardW: It's not that the default is to use double-quotes as escape characters, it's that the default is to use quoting instead of escaping, with double-quotes as the quote characters, which means that each quote character has to be quoted separately from the rest of the string… which may seem like a weird design, but it probably goes back decades to something like Excel 1.0 trying to be almost like Lotus but with some minor differences to avoid potential IP claims…

Comment: this was moment of enlightenment. The meaning of `quotechar` is not what one will intuitively understand. (also it is csv.QUOTE_NONE)

Answer (score 0):

Quotes get escaped because your data could contain a comma. You probably don't want a CSV file if you don't want quotes escaped.  Just join on a comma (this will break downstream if your data has a comma in it)